# Tumblr API v2 post getting error not authorized

Tags: api, post, oauth-2.0, tumblr

When I post an article with a few words it is Ok but when I try to post an article that has more than 100 words get the error "not authorized".

Here is the post request (I changed the oauth tokens to make then public)

```
POST /v2/blog/mysite.tumblr.com/post HTTP/1.1
TE: deflate,gzip;q=0.3
Connection: TE, close
Authorization: OAuth oauth_nonce="b9282afe60b7f",oauth_timestamp="13462177",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_consumer_key="CnVDC1PdI5d26DRZpJ88JYuO",oauth_token="qTIeLpAQWSIZ2wYBFoUeZMQjkgRDlvEGLjJw7xjo",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_signature="GG8ywH0iq94C6a8jpwryktIE%3D"
Host: api.tumblr.com
User-Agent: libwww-perl/6.04
Content-Length: 781
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

body=Ancient+Domains+of+Mystery+(ADOM)+is+one+of+the+most+successful+roguelike+games+ever+created%2C+with+downloads+in+the+millions+and+many+more+every+day.+ADOM+was+the+first+roguelike+to+add+a+true+role-playing+experience+to+the+roguelike+genre+and+it+has+inspired+countless+numbers+of+new+role+playing%2Froguelike+games+you+may+have+seen+in+last+2+decades.%C2%A0+ADOM+was+in+development+from+1994+until+November+2002%2C+when+the+last+build+was+released.+Now%2C%C2%A0creator+Thomas+Biskup+is+resurrecting%C2%A0it%2C+with+a%C2%A0crowd%C2%A0funding+campaign+on+Indiegogo.++This+new+incarnation+of+ADOM+has+already+surpassed+its+funding+and+three+stretch+goals.+You+can+expect+following+new+features+in+the+game%2C+including+a+full+graphical+version&title=Linux+resources&tags=linux

HTTP/1.1 401 Not Authorized
```

Comment: What was your resolution to this issue? Finding lots of other folks having the same 401 problem during posting (but other actions like /user/info work fine), but nobody is posting the fix.